# Airflow 1.10.10 error connecting to google cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, airflow

**Apache-Airflow version 1.10.10**

I have set up the correct project ID name and key directory in the google default platform connection. However, I keep getting this error below. I am not sure what is causing it. I was wondering if anyone else have this problem?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DmxG.jpg)

Thanks,
Tan

Comment: Don't post picture of the error, instead paste it directly as text.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are passing an argument of “soruce_object” instead of “source_objects” to the GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator. Try correcting the spelling of the argument; that should resolve the exception.